# How to calculate height and width of different objects using camera only in iOS?

Tags: iphone, opencv, ios8, camera, alassetslibrary

I want to calculate Height and width of different objects using camera.

[image]

is there any way to do it in objective c or in swift?

Comment: This is not a good question, what have you tried to solve your problem? What research have you done? There is no magic way to do something like this and Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask for a complete solution without having put in some effort yourself..

Comment: I need idea of doing this. Haven't seen any body's discussion on stackoverflow for this. See My question is "is there any way?"

Answer (score 0):

To do this, read about camera calibration. Also look into OpenCV, which has many camera calibration functions that you can use to solve the problem you are interested in.